# Replace ,{} from a string

Tags: c#

Remove ,{} from a string using Replace() function

Hi all
I have a string like below example

```
string str=@"},
        
        {}"; // Before this {} i have included 2 Tabs
```

Here i want to remove the `",{}"` from the str. But when i used `str.Replace(",\n\t\t{}","");` it is not giving correct output.
but when i used

```
str.Replace(@",

        {}","");// Included new line and two tabs
```

it is working.

Is there any other option to remove ,{} from str with a single line operation instead of above two line replace() function.

Comment: Tanks in advance? Is this a declaration of war? Anyway, you might look at regular expressions since they can handle misc whitespace.

Comment: Your code is correct, but you did not consider the spaces, it will be fixed with this code "str.Replace(",\r\n\r\n        {}", "");"

Comment: I hope you're not parsing JSON manually....

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, you are hysterical lol

Answer (score 1):

As [@ProgrammingLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/programmingllama) said, regex is your friend

```
string str=@"},
    
    {}"; // Before this {} i have included 2 Tabs

string trimmedStr = Regex.Replace(str, @",\s+\{\}", "");
```

Where `\s` means match any whitespace, `+` means "one or more times" and `\{` and `\}` are your curly braces